# Updating HTML Table through web form?

Tags: php, html, webforms

So I have an HTML table on a webpage that I need to be updated. I have been updating my friend's website's table by editing the HTML file for him, but I will be leaving and need an easy solution for him to be able to update this table without having to dig into his HTML files.

The solution I came up with was using a webform, where he could simply type in values, and it would update the table on the HTML page as needed. How would I go about this? Do I need to use a database?

This is the table on the webpage (I would need to update the date at the top, the names, and phone numbers):

```
      <div id="content">
    <h1>Weekend Support (15-Feb-2014 & 16-Feb-2014)</h1>
            <table style = "width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td><b>Track</b></td>
                <td><b>Name</b></td> 
                <td><b>Phone</b></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>RTR/SPP</td>
                <td>Name1</td> 
                <td>############</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>OTC/EDW</td>
                <td>Name2</td> 
                <td>############</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CFS/MPM</td>
                <td>Name3</td> 
                <td>############</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ESA</td>
                <td>Name4</td> 
                <td>############</td>
            </tr>
            </tr>

            </table>
  </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I would use a database

Comment: I would prefer database but XML is another good option

Comment: @Fallen Do you have an example of how that would work?

Comment: Look into using JS templating with a JSON data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan and DrRoach are correct. The best implementation for this would to use a Mysql Database and PHP to create your Content Management System. You would create a php page that he can log into and update the certain attributes of the table. I highly recommend doing this and learning about CMS structure.

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can go about this is by using a MySQL database as this would be the best practice, you can however use a .txt file and simply read the values out of there for the form which would be easier and quicker to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a database as well. W3Schools has a great intro if you are new to this: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp
You could build a simple form for them to use. Most ISPs that support PHP also support mySQL.